# How do I count the number of 'H' in 'FTR' column

Tags: python, pandas, list, count

I have a column imported from csv called FTR. It has possible items: H, A, D. When I try to count the number of 'H' in column 'FTR' i get 0 back? Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('./football_stats.csv')
print(df) 

homeWin = df['FTR']
totalHomeWins = {}

for i in homeWin:
    if homeWin.item == 'H':
        totalHomeWins += 1
    else:
        totalHomeWins = 0

print(totalHomeWins)
```

FTR column has the following items "H", "A", "D"

Comment: please put the code you have and the data you have as text so we don't have to download and or retype your code to get to the question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is a good guide on what to put in a question.

Comment: In your code if `homeWin.item` is not `H` then `totalHomeWins` is set to `0`. You probably only want to replace `totalHomeWins = 0` with `pass` or just remove the whole `else` block

Comment: @dariofac I removed the else block but that returns an empty {}

Comment: @StephenWood that is because you inizialized `totalHomeWins` as a dictionary (`{}`). If you initialize it as `totalHomeWins = 0` it should work (or it doesn't enter the cycle or the `if` is never verified).

Comment: @dariofac - schoolboy error on my part! I've changed totalHomeWins to initialize as 0 but I still get a '0' output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
totalhomewin=df['FTR'].value_counts()['H']
```

Comment: @StephenWood No problem, accept and upvote if the answer was helpful. cheers

Answer (score 2):

I see some problems in your code.

First of all, the `totalHomeWins` variable should be initialized not as a dictionary, but as as integer: `totalHomeWins = 0`.

Then, when you are iterating over `homeWin` (which I suppose is a list) you are performing the following check in the `if`:

```
for i in homeWin:
    if homeWin.item == 'H':
        totalHomeWins += 1
    else:
        totalHomeWins = 0
```

Here I see two errors:

The first one is that `homeWin.item` should be replaced by `i.item` (`i` is the element in the list `homeWin` you are looking at each iteration).

The second one is that the `else` part can be removed or replaced by the following:

```
else:
    totalHomeWins =+ 0
```

Otherwise `totalHomeWins` would be reset to `0` when the `if` is not verified.

Wrapping all together, the following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('./football_stats.csv')
print(df) 

homeWin = df['FTR']
totalHomeWins = 0

for i in homeWin:
    if i.item == 'H':
        totalHomeWins += 1

print(totalHomeWins)
```